# Take the frequency of sum and col name of a dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("Google,Amazon", "Amazon,Yahoo"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How is it possible from this commands:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    text = strsplit(text, ","),
    value = 1
    ) %>% 
  unnest(text) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = text,
    values_from = value,
    values_fill = list(value = 0)
  )
```

Receive an output with two columns, one with the colnames and the other with the sum of every column. Expected output:

```
data.frame(name = c("Google","Amazon","Yahoo"), sum = c(1,2,1))
```

Comment: Try `data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$text), ','))))`

Comment: I do not think that this question should be closed based on the reference given above.

Comment: @MarBlo Why not? It is the same thing. In fact I copy/pasted (and added `data.frame)`my comment from the accepted answer of that link

Comment: @Sotos. Because you think it is the same but you have to respect that someone post here a question depending on the problem he/she phases. So as an answer could be the right, as refered in the guides, even if it is not totally fits the question the same should be for a question.

Comment: @Nathalie First of all I never showed disrespect. This is a big accusation from your part! If you notice, I answered in comments before targeting as dupe AND I gave a **BETTER** dplyr alternative to the answer given to you. So your comment for respect is at the very least unfortunate.

Comment: As for hammering, there are rules in stack overflow. If a question has been answered before, then we close them as dupes because they create unnecessary noise to the site making the search for answers impossible. So while you accuse me for lack of respect, you might want to read the rules of the site

Comment: All that needed to be done was `unnest(text) %>% count(text)` instead of `pivot_wider`. This would also mean that `value = 1` is redundant, `count` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("Google,Amazon", "Amazon,Yahoo"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#>   id          text
#> 1  1 Google,Amazon
#> 2  2  Amazon,Yahoo

df %>% 
  separate(col=text, into = c('a', 'b')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = a:b) %>% 
  count(value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   value      n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 Amazon     2
#> 2 Google     1
#> 3 Yahoo      1
```

Comment: You can also use `separate_rows` and avoid pivoting to long format. i.e. `df %>% separate_rows(text, sep = ',') %>% count(text)`